# Keep cmd open after invokation of a cli application with Autohotkey

Tags: windows, autohotkey, cmd.exe

How can one keep the cmd window open after an invokation a cli application with Autohotkey? I need to see the program's output, but it exits and causes the window to vanish.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of running directly your CLI application, run it through `cmd` with the `-k` parameter :

```
cmd /k <cli application>
```

`/k` will prevent the command prompt to close after starting the application.

Answer (score 0):

You could invoke the application within a BAT or CMD script and follow it with the `pause` command which will wait for a keypress before exiting.